# Get checkbox status as soon as it is checked or unchecked

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current status of checkbox as soon as it is check or unchecked. Based on that show the Toast message. Here is my code so far.

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean Alarm = getPrefs.getBoolean("cbAlarm", true);
    if(Alarm == true) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if(Alarm == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "UnChecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

How can I achieve this. Please help.

**Edit**
here is my xml file

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Enable/Disable Alarm"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="cbAlarm"
    android:summary="Enable or disable alarm" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)  findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);

myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
        if (isChecked){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
             Toast.makeText(this, "UnChecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this but here I am using CheckBoxPreference. How can I do this with CheckBoxPreference? Please see my update above

Comment: CheckBoxPreference has OnPreferenceClickListener()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html